# It's possible to save the data of the ViewModel with Knockout JS after refresh page?

Tags: knockout.js, page-refresh, savestate

I would like to know if is possible to save the changes in the observable values and get the last state of the ViewModel after refreshing a page.

Comment: You could use local storage for this. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a [ko extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) to achieve that.

There are some out there one of which is [knockout.persist](https://github.com/spoike/knockout.persist).

With this binding you can do something like this:

```
// Will automatically load and save the value if it exists in the localStorage
this.persistedValue = ko.observable().extend({ persist: 'persistedValue' });

// Will automatically load and save the array if it exists in the localStorage
this.persistedArray = ko.observableArray().extend({ persist: 'persistedArray' });
```

It works pretty nicely overall as I have used it in some projects.

Now if localStorage is not an option you can look into persisting the state via cookie in a similar fashion or via JSON.stringify addition to the URL in the browser.

It all depends on what the constrains on your task/use case are.